# Read map from yaml file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-el

I have problem reading additional properties from yaml file (not `application.yaml`). I'm trying to parse map of string/string values however I get `NumberFormatException`. Seems Spring tries to read it as integer.
Here is an example of map:

```
id:
  id1: -1001978483459
  id2: -1001978483457
```

And properties class:

```
@Data
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/id.yml")
public class ChatIdProperties {

    @Value("#{${id}}")
    Map<String, String> id;

}
```

I think it should be possible to enforce Spring parsing it as string or long since numbers used in yaml are big but I have no idea how to do that. I've tried to use `!!str` tag and had zero result

Answer (score 0):

application.yml:

```
myapp:
  ids:
    id1: -1001978483459
    id2: -1001978483457
```

MyAppProperties.java:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
public class MyAppProperties {

    private Map<String, String> ids;

    // accessors
}
```

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyAppProperties.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> runnerListener(MyAppProperties myAppProperties) {
        return applicationReadyEvent -> System.out.println(myAppProperties.getIds());
    }

}
```

Output:

```
{id1=-1001978483459, id2=-1001978483457}
```

---

Or if you really need to do this without "myapp" prefix in properties:

application.yml:

```
id:
  id1: -1001978483459
  id2: -1001978483457
```

IdProperties.java:

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public class IdProperties {

    private Map<String, String> id;

    // accessors
}
```

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(IdProperties.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> runnerListener(IdProperties idProperties) {
        return applicationReadyEvent -> System.out.println(idProperties.getId());
    }

}
```

Output:

```
{id1=-1001978483459, id2=-1001978483457}
```

---

If you need to store ids in.yml and not in application.yml, then one easy way is to import id.yml:

application.yml:

```
spring.config.import: id.yml
```

(available since Spring Boot 2.4 afaik)

id.yml:

```
id:
  id1: -1001978483459
  id2: -1001978483457
```

The rest of my answer will fork fine.

---

In your original post the problem is that @PropertySource doesn't read yml files, only properties files. So one another way is making @PropertySource able to read yml files by creating custom PropertySourceFactory. This approach is described here: baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource

Comment: The point is not storing values in application.yaml. Otherwise I wouldn't create this topic

Comment: Then your first problem is that @PropertySource doesn't read yml files, only properties. One easy way you can do is import id.yml to application.yml: add `spring.config.import: id.yml` to your application.yml. The rest of my answer will work fine. I wull update my answer. Another way is making @PropertySource able to read yml files by creating custom PropertySourceFactory. This approach is described here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource

Comment: I'll at this example and report back. Thanks

Comment: @BANTYC Had a chance to look into this?

Comment: Sorry, had no opportunity to check. We decided to do this other way and paste it in aplication.yml and everything runs smoothly

Answer (score 0):

The yaml file being read has values in the format, which by default will be read as Numerical values. To enforce value be read as String, the values can be enclosed in quotes(i.e. if you are the owner of yaml file, and can modify it)
This ought to do it.

```
id:
  id1: '-1001978483459'
  id2: '-1001978483457'
```